# Resources for Faddeev-Popov method. (Specifically for diffeomorphism gauge fixing.)

Tags: resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, path-integral, diffeomorphism-invariance, ghosts

I am struggling to get the same result as this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(80)90423-X) (eq. 3.10) for my ghost field when gauge-fixing diffeomorphisms in linearized gravity. I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the direction of some resources that could guide me through this method. I have currently tried it following the outlines from Peskin & Schroeder and Polchinski but I have been unable to get the same result.

Comment: is the equation you are referring to, namely (3.10), also here, eg (D3)? https://inspirehep.net/literature/189578 (i don’t have easy access to the paper you refer to) And are you sure you have accounted for different conventions?